# HTML Template Navbar not working as i want

Tags: html, laravel, navbar, nav

Here is my template and its NavBar section.my problem is if i click on **Trainee Detail** it is not redirect to the page i want.im using laravel project for that.

Before i press that link url is **http://127.0.0.1:8000/TraineeAttendance**
then if i click Trainee Details nav link same url will appear.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home#">MOB<span class="logo-dec">ITEL</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li class=""><a href="URL::to('AddAttendance')">Trainee Detail</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#service">Mark Attendance</a></li>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                                       aria-expanded="false">
                                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                                Logout
                                            </a>

                                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                                                  style="display: none;">
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            </form>


                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Try this one `href="{{URL::to('AddAttendance')}}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the brackets at

```
<li class=""><a href="URL::to('AddAttendance')">Trainee Detail</a></li>
```

You should try it like this:

```
{{URL::to('AddAttendance')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
    <li class=""><a href="URL::to('AddAttendance')">Trainee Detail</a></li>
```

To

```
    <li class=""><a href="{{URL::to('AddAttendance')}}">Trainee Detail</a></li>
```